# How can I replace an input with a textarea preserving all attributes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attributes, properties

I have a text input that I'd like to replace with a textarea, preserving all of the attributes. How can I do this with jQuery?

Sample input:

```
<input type="text" name="newfeature" id="newfeature"
  class="form-required" tabindex="3"
  aria-required="true" />
```

Desired output:

```
<textarea type="text" name="newfeature" id="newfeature"
  class="form-required" tabindex="3"
  aria-required="true"></textarea>
```

I know this can be done manually using the `.prop()` selector and specifying each attribute/property, but how can I do it dynamically?

Also, this is not necessary, but would it possible to preserve the bindings when doing this?

Comment: `<textarea>` elements don't have a `type` attribute...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas the .prop() takes care of that. It also sets the value property straight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This also works with the `value` attribute correctly:

```
$('input').each(function() {

    var attrs = {};        

    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
       attrs[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    $(this).replaceWith($('<textarea>').prop(attrs));
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FyYDT/

**ADDED**

If you want jQuery events to pass along (not recommended), you need to re-bind them. Something like:

```
$('input').click(function() {

    alert('hey');

}).each(function() {

    var attrs = {},
        ta = $('<textarea>');

    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
       attrs[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    $.each($(this).data('events'), function(i, f) {
        $.each(f, function(){
            ta.bind(i, this.handler);
        });
    });

    $(this).replaceWith(ta.prop(attrs));

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FyYDT/1/

Comment: Added event cloning as well, although I would personally rather use event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply loop through the `input`s attributes:

```
function makeInputTextarea(inputElem) {
    var $textarea = $("<textarea></textarea>");
    $.each(inputElem.attributes, function(i, attrib){
        var name = attrib.name;
        var value = attrib.value;
        if(name === "type") return; // textareas don't have a "type" attribute
        $textarea.attr(name, value);
    });
    return $textarea;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').parent().each(function({
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(<\/)input/gi, "$1textarea").replace(/(<textarea[^>]*)value\=['"](.*)['"]([^>]*)\/>/, "$1>$2</textarea>"));
    }));
});
```

Should do the trick?

You could do a

```
$('input, textarea').live('click', function() {
    // do actions!
});
```

To preserve bindings

Comment: Right, but remember that there is no inline `value=""` attribute on the textarea. So it would be better do loop through the attributes somehow, grabbing them with `.prop('attrName')` and setting them with `.prop('attrName',value)` rather than regExing it. Also regarding the bindings I'd like to preserve them - this would be a plugin and so I can't edit the original bindings.